# Excel converts DateTime to Int

Tags: excel, vba

I'm importing table from `SQL Server` to Excel by `VBA`. 
Here is the part of code

```
For Each fld In rs.Fields
            Sheet1.Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "@"
            Sheet1.Cells(row, col).Value = fld
            col = col + 1
        Next
```

I have field in `SQL Server` which is `DateTime`, but it is imported to `Excel` as `int` (some weird number appears). I've specified explicitly

```
Sheet1.Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "@"
```

but that didn't help. How I can import DateTime field from SQL Server to `Excel` either as `DateTime` or `Text`

And I want to keep format the same as in SQL Server, which is `2017-11-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Format the cell as Date?

Comment: @TimWilliams , I can format, but when I rerun VBA, it's being overwritten with Integer again

Comment: If you Debug.Print the date field value what does it look like?

Comment: That look like integer, @TimWilliams . Try to write some date into Excel cell, and then format it as Integer, same thing. However, SQL Server data type is DateTime

Comment: What's the exact code you use to format the cell as Date?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't format it at all, all formatting can be seen in my post above. Moreover, I don't want to format manually

Comment: Do you have a time in your DateTime fields?  If not, the date part will be an integral number (e.g. 5 November 2017 is day number 43044), so you should just format the cell using a Date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by converting datetime into varchar in query inside VBA

```
convert(varchar(55),runDate,121)
```

Excel somehow can't understand DateTime datatype

Comment: An equivalent result could probably be obtained by just changing the line in your code which is formatting the cell as text (i.e. `Sheet1.Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "@"`) to instead format the cell as a date/time (e.g. `Sheet1.Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"`.  That would then allow you to continue using the cell as a date/time rather than have to convert it back to that each time you want to use it.